# What are the exact dimensions of Shimano disc brake split (cotter) pins?

Tags: shimano, brakes, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-pads

What are the exact dimensions of Shimano disc brake split (cotter) pins, such as part nr. 25 (Y8DB06100) on BR-MT410 caliper (https://si.shimano.com/en/ev/BR-MT410-4663)?

- Looking to buy generic replacements in bulk
- Not sure if sizes of these differ on different models of Shimano calipers, information on that would be appreciated as well

Comment: There are 3 different sizes/shapes.

Comment: They are sold with the brake pads, so it may not be relevant to buy them separately in bulk.

Comment: @Renaud I do not always replace pads when doing bleed or deep clean - they are often reasonably uncontaminated and have a lot of miles left in them. And where I am, in Denmark, Shimano original pins as separate item seem ridiculously overpriced compared to bulk packs of 100 excellent automotive/construction stainless pins that are available in all kinds of sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the results of my measurements with an electronic caliper set on millimeters. This pin came with Shimano's GO4S metallic pads spec'd for use in BR-M6100, BR-M8100 calipers among others.
Not pictured:

> Width of metal making up the cotter pin: 2.37-2.40mm.

> Girth of the closed portion of the cotter pin (the two ends of the metal where they come together after forming the round eye): 2.53mm.

> Length of tail (longer side one grasps to pry apart pin): 3.05mm

[image: cotter pin]

[image: cotter pin2]

[image: cotter pin eye]